# Xamarin Google Maps centering

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

I made a Xamarin App with Google Maps. I added on that map multiple markers that show shops around the location of the device. And when I open the app I made it center on the nearest shop.

The problem is that when I try to swipe the map to see what is around, it comes back centering to the closest marker. I want to disable that.Is that possible ?

The code that adds the markers is in OnLocationChanged method.

Thank you.

```
private void GetCompaniesByLocation(double latitude,double longitude)
    {
        string url = "http://127.0.0.1/testapi/handler.php/latlong/" + latitude + "/" + longitude;
        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.here_icon);

        Companies[] onlines = CallRestServiceCompanies(url);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Companies online in onlines)
        {
            if (i == 0) {
                locationPoint = new LatLng(online.address_lat, online.address_long);
                CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(locationPoint, 16);
                mMap.AnimateCamera(camera);
                i++;
            }
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(online.address_lat, online.address_long);
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            options.SetPosition(latlng);
            options.SetTitle(online.company_name);
            options.SetSnippet(online.company_website);
            options.SetIcon(icon);

            mMap.AddMarker(options);
        }
}
```

And OnLocationChanged method:

```
public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        currentLocation = location;
        if(currentLocation != null)
        {
            GetCompaniesByLocation(currentLocation.Latitude, currentLocation.Longitude);
        }
    }
```

And Of course this is continuously running. I want to be triggered only when the location is actually changing.

Comment: Thats not the default behaviour, you must be doing it, please post your code.

Comment: To be able to set the camera to the closest shop I used AnimateCamera. Otherwise It would show the whole world and not only close by.

Comment: You are moving the camera when onLocationChanged is called. You cant control when is it going to be called.

Comment: @Nanoc can you tell me how ?

Comment: Move it only the first time, only on a button click... anything but in onLocationChanged.